# LIMIT to one row per ID

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

This query gives me multiple hits because of each `assetid` may contain many `vb.title`. How can I limit the result to only 1 hit for each `assetid`?

```
'select DISTINCT v.id,
           v.purchasedate,
           v.customerid,
           v.assetid,
           va.description,
           vb.title
  from purchases v,
           asset va,
           assetdescription vb
 where customerid = '$kid'
   and v.assetid = va.id
   and vb.assetid = va.id
 order by v.purchasedate'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care which you get, you can use something like this:

```
select max(v.id),
       max(v.purchasedate),
       max(v.customerid),
       v.assetid,
       max(va.description),
       max(vb.title)
  from purchases v,
           asset va,
           assetdescription vb
 where customerid = '$kid'
   and v.assetid = va.id
   and vb.assetid = va.id
 group by v.assetid
 order by v.purchasedate;
```

If you want e.g. the "latest", then you can use something like this:

```
select t.id,
       t.purchasedate,
       t.customerid,
       t.assetid,
       t.description,
       t.title
from (
    select v.id,
           v.purchasedate,
           v.customerid,
           v.assetid,
           va.description,
           vb.title,
           row_number() over (partition by v.assetid order by v.purchasedate desc) as rn
      from purchases v,
               asset va,
               assetdescription vb
     where customerid = '$kid'
       and v.assetid = va.id
       and vb.assetid = va.id
) t
where rn = 1
order by v.purchasedate
```

The decision which one to take is controlled by the ordering inside the window definition (`partion by v.assetid order by ....`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pick the row with the earliest `purchasedate` for each `assetid` as your example seems to indicate, this query may be preferable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.assetid)
       v.id
      ,v.purchasedate
      ,v.customerid
      ,v.assetid
      ,va.description
      ,vb.title
FROM   purchases v
JOIN   asset va ON va.id = v.assetid
JOIN   assetdescription vb ON vb.assetid = va.id
WHERE  customerid = '$kid'
ORDER  BY assetid, v.purchasedate;
```

The leading expressions in `ORDER BY` have to be the same as the expressions in `DISTINCT ON`. You can wrap the whole query into a subquery to `ORDER BY purchasedate` in the outer query to order the complete result, too.